# What is the recommended annotation for a facade layer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am implementing some of my business logic in my facade layer (which does some calculations and makes calls to service layers etc). What is the recommended stereotype for this layer, similar to @Service on service layer ? I use @Component as of now. Is it worth creating a new annotation as I'm using the same pattern across multiple projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether you need to implement some logic on all the facade methods. For example , suppose you need to apply an AOP aspect on all the facade methods , by making a new specific annotation for it , you can locate the correct facade methods and process them based on the presence of this new annotation rather than a hard-coded list.

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) also mentions it:

> Therefore, you can annotate your component classes with @Component,
> but, by annotating them with @Repository, @Service, or @Controller
> instead, your classes are more properly suited for processing by tools
> or associating with aspects. For example, these stereotype annotations
> make ideal targets for pointcuts. @Repository, @Service, and
> @Controller can also carry additional semantics in future releases of
> the Spring Framework. Thus, if you are choosing between using
> @Component or @Service for your service layer, @Service is clearly the
> better choice. Similarly, as stated earlier, @Repository is already
> supported as a marker for automatic exception translation in your
> persistence layer.

Here as Spring needs to locate all repository classes to apply an automatic exception translation for them , so it creates a new specific annotation `@Repository`.